# How constructor work

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

Update question:
Why we have "I am being constructed". 
And where I can lean that?. 
Im reading C++ book at university but I did find that.

Im so sorry because some mistake.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct President {
    std::string name;
    std::string country;
    int year;

    President(std::string p_name, std::string p_country, int p_year)
        : name(std::move(p_name))
        , country(std::move(p_country))
        , year(p_year)
    {
        std::cout << "I am being constructed.\n";
    }
    President(President&& other)
        : name(std::move(other.name))
        , country(std::move(other.country))
        , year(other.year)
    {
        std::cout << "I am being moved.\n";
    }
    President& operator=(const President& other) = default;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<President> reElections;
    std::cout << "\npush_back:\n";
    reElections.push_back(President("Franklin Delano Roosevelt", "the USA", 1936));

    for (President const& president : reElections) {
        std::cout << president.name << " was re-elected president of "
                  << president.country << " in " << president.year << ".\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

push_back:
I am being constructed.
I am being moved.

\nThank you so much.

Comment: What is confusing you? The constructor function is called here: `President("Franklin Delano Roosevelt", "the USA", 1936)`

Comment: When you create an *object*, an *instance* of a class, that object is *constructed* and the appropriate constructor is being called.

Comment: You got your example from cppreference. cplusplus.com/reference and cppreference.com are the two different, competing, online C++ references

Comment: Im sorry because my mistake. I was update question

Comment: If your c++ book didn't explain the basics of constructors then find a different book or read it more carefully.

Comment: @JasonC okie this is exactly what I want. If you now ??

Answer (score 1):

Creating an instance of class automatically calls the constructor. In your program constructor of "President" is being called when you are *emplacing* an element of vector with "Nelson Mandela, and when *pushing* back"Franklin Roosevelt".

Comment: Im sorry because my mistake. I was update question

Answer (score 1):

The example here is probably intending to show that `std::vector::emplace_back` constructs in place, but `push_back` moves.

We can see more detail of what happens using the (more verbose) version of President

```
struct President {
    std::string name;
    std::string country;
    int year;

    President(std::string p_name, std::string p_country, int p_year)
        : name(std::move(p_name))
        , country(std::move(p_country))
        , year(p_year)
    {
        std::cout << "I am being constructed at " << this << ".\n";
    }
    President(President&& other)
        : name(std::move(other.name))
        , country(std::move(other.country))
        , year(other.year)
    {
        std::cout << "I am being moved from " << &other << " to " << this << ".\n";
    }
    President(const President& other)
        : name(other.name)
        , country(other.country)
        , year(other.year)
    {
        std::cout << "I am being copied from " << &other << " to " << this << ".\n";
    }
    ~President()
    {
        std::cout << "I am being destructed at " << this << ".\n";
    }
};
```

Example output:

```
emplace_back:
I am being constructed at 0x2b2b57e17c30.

push_back:
I am being constructed at 0x7ffcb9a0cec0.
I am being moved from 0x7ffcb9a0cec0 to 0x2b2b57e17cb0.
I am being destructed at 0x7ffcb9a0cec0.

Contents:
Nelson Mandela was elected president of South Africa in 1994.
Franklin Delano Roosevelt was re-elected president of the USA in 1936.
I am being destructed at 0x2b2b57e17cb0.
I am being destructed at 0x2b2b57e17c30.
```

Comment: Im sorry because my mistake. I was update question